# ErrorException Undefined variable $data

Tags: laravel

### In the database notification, I want to send a notification to a specific user

### **But in the constructor, $data is shown as undefined**

### **here Employee is my model name and I want to notify employee id 1 in the employee table and data will be inserted in the employee**

```
$data=Employee::create([
        'first_name'=>$request->input('first_name'),
        'last_name'=>$request->input('last_name'),
        'username'=>$request->input('username'),
        'email'=>$request->input('email'),
        'password'=>$request->input('password'),
        'confirm_password'=>$request->input('confirm_password'),
    ]);
    

    $admin=Employee::find(1);
    
    $admin->notify(new NotifyAdmin($data));
```

**notification class**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Models\Employee; 


class NotifyAdmin extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, Notifiable;
    private $val;

   
    public function __construct(Employee $employee)
    {
       
        $this->val=$data;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

   
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'username'=> $this->val->username
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: your $data is passed as an argument but your constructor defines $employee parameter. Therefore $this->val = $employee; should work.

Comment: if i use $employee it shows BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Employee::notify()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem because you write $employee in the constructor parameter but you use data , so data not exist , change it to be like this :-

```
   public function __construct(Employee $employee)
    {
       
        $this->val=$employee;
    }
```

Comment: it shows this error  BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Models\Employee::notify()

Comment: are you  using Notifiable trait in your model ?

Comment: My model is Employee and there is no notifiable trait. I am not familiar with this and I don't know how to use it?

Comment: to make your model listen to the notification you should use Notifiable trait on your model like this :- 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

Comment: .........Wow, it works. Thank You so much. You know i have been spent 2 days solving this problem. But I didn't. Now it solved. Thank you